# Who was/were the leaders during the Asarah Harugei Malchus?

Tags: history, midrash, tannaim

I know that the Asarah Harugei Malchus took place over generations. Nonetheless, who is recognized as being the original antagonist? Who is the one who went to Chazal about the claim about Yosef's brothers?

Comment: Somehow I doubt there was ever any such Roman leader who went to the sages with this argument. That would have demanded killing ten sages then and there, but obviously this didn't happen since, as you said, the killings spanned generations. I think it's a symbolic-aggadic opening intended to connect their deaths together and perhaps offer some reasoning too.

Comment: @Harel13 so then R’ Yishmael never went up to shomayim to ask if the gezeira was real? That’s a real far fetched sorry to make up.

Comment: @Chatzkel Don't know, but I think a number of mefarshim ask about what's happening in the piyut, since it cannot possibly be literal. Once you say that it's a metaphor for something happening in shamayim (which I think some of them do), that will apply to many parts of the piyut.

Comment: @Chatzkel However, the details of the actual deaths of many of the chachamim there do come from midrashim and gemaros.

Comment: @Chatzkel Do you mean "a real far fetched *story* to make up"? If so I don't follow what you're trying to say. The extremely super natural character of the story is exactly what makes it sound made up.

Comment: We know Hadrian was the one who killed Rabbi Akiva. According to third Wikipedia entry, he was the one who was the antagonist of the story with the brothers. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_Martyrs

Comment: @DoubleAA yes I meant story. I mean to say that if it never happened, why create such a narrative, with 3 days and asking malachim etc

Comment: Midrash Eicha 1:9 connects the Asara Harugim to the sale of Yosef. https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Mishlei.1.9?lang=bi

Comment: @Chatzkel That's an easy question. It makes for a good story with a good message about the rabbis accepting the punishment or whatever. Why does anyone write fiction (besides lousy authors selling trash)? I can't prove to you any particular midrash is fiction or not, but if you can accept that some are there to make a point and not to relate history (as is the position of numerous geonim and rishonim), then you clearly understand the answer to your question.

Comment: @Chatzkel I second what has been said by MichoelR and Double AA. No, I don't take everything in Chazal to be literal. I don't follow Rambam on everything, but he did state that many things in Chazal were intended to be symbolic. As an example, what would you think if you heard Reish Lakish say that Iyov never existed? This is brought as an an unnamed minority opinion in the gemara in Bava Batra and apparently countered,

Comment: but in Beresheet Rabbah R"L says so explicitly. https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bereishit_Rabbah.57.4?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE&lang=he Did he really mean that or maybe he didn't mean it literally? But then, why present it as literal? Just one random example of many.

Comment: Even Artscroll in its commentary says that this is a fictionalized version of the story, as it is historically impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Can’t give you a source but from all the different versions that I’ve heard of the story, it was either Turnus Rufus (the brutal governor who had a particular quarrel with Rabbi Akiva since he stole his wife) or Hadrian. And btw if you want a really great and detailed account of the Ten Martyrs with background, watch this video: https://youtu.be/PZwXmZE87_s

Comment: So you identify the Rabban/Rabbi Shimon in the story with Rabbi Shimon ben Azzai or Rabban Shimon ben Gamliel II and Rabbi Yishmael ben Kohen Gadol with a post-destruction tanna?

Comment: @Harel13 no why do you say that? I believe like most people do that those two figured were killed before the others, around the time of the churban. I think I agree with your comment above of how the whole story of them being summoned by the Roman leader is merely for dramatic effect and symbolism

Comment: The above suggestions are some other opinions for whom Rabbi Shimon and Rabbi Yishmael in the aggadata are, based on different versions of it. So if I understand you correctly, you think on the one hand that the opening was written to be symbolic yet on the other hand you think that the author did have a certain Roman leader in mind, but for whatever reason decided not to include his name?

Comment: Idk whatever it doesn’t really matter what I think. Though from the fact that different sources say either Hadrian or Turnus Rufus, that shows that there is some discrepancy and a possible answer could simply be that it’s symbolic but each different account chose a different Roman to villainize

Comment: Well, this is your answer and very likely based on what you think. Are the sources you're referring to sources about the versions of Asseret Harugei Malchut or simply sources regarding the deaths of different sages?